# eb init on existing project gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm moving over to a new machine, and when I run `"eb init"` on my existing project, then select region, and keep the application name, I get an error saying:

```
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. User: arn:aws:iam::********:user/**** is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplication on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1:*********:application/*****
```

The same happens when I try with `eb init .`

It seems to think I am trying to create a new application, when I just want to access an existing one.

I copied the ~/.aws/config from my old machine, still no joy though

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong access key, as I had copied over an older version of the '~/.aws/config' file by mistake :/